# JHipster Generator v4.14 is not showing option of React

Tags: jhipster

While creating an app using JHipster, it is not showing **React** option for question *"Which Framework would you like to use for the client?"*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In v4.14.x, React support is still “experimental”, so you need to run `jhipster --experimental` to enable React support.

But no work has been done for React in v4.14.x the last weeks, so you should use the Generator JHipster `v5.0.0-beta.1` instead.